# Generating Worksheets using the same template in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have an Excel template where I am using HLookup to populate one row of data. Is there a way to use macros to:

1. Generate multiple worksheets based on the number of rows in the workbook?
2. Have multiple worksheets that would look like the template?

In short, I have two worksheets: Data Summary and Template. Currently I copy and paste one row at a time into the data summary and the data appears in the proper section of the template in the other worksheet.

Is there a way that I can speed up the process by doing more than one at a time using macros?

Comment: What happens if you paste all the data at one time instead of pasting each row?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not exactly sure how your file looks, I'll have to guess a little.
But you can try this:

```
Sub distribute()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long, i As Integer
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To k

        Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        sh.Rows(i).Copy Range("A2")

    Next

End Sub
```

Note that the "**A**" in `sh.Range("A1048576")`defines the column to search for rows.

This code:

- Counts to the last row used in the specified column and creates that many new worksheets (copies of the "template" worksheet).
- Copies row 1 from the "Data" sheet into A2 of the first new worksheet (because I'm just assuming there is a table with a header there), row 2 from "Data" into the second new worksheet and so on.
- Will **NOT** ignore empty rows between first and last row, and will create an empty sheet.

Maybe this can be modified to fit your needs.
Good luck!

Comment: After reading the question a few  times, I start to wonder exactly what you want to do. If you copy the data TO the data summary, you are copying them from the template? Why do you need so many copies of the template?
I'd love to improve my answer, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to accomplish.